# Javascript - how to give variables in a loop names like var_1, var_2 etc

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am playing around with the Google Maps API V3.

I want to create a series of markers on a map.

I followed a tutorial and got:

Now this code adds one marker - the first one.

I am completely new to Javascript but from my PHP knowledge, I am thinking that the reason this is not working is because all of the markers are being stored in the var named 'm'.

I.E Number 2 replaces Number 1

My confusion however is that if this were the case, Marker 2 would be shown not Marker 1.

Could anyone postulate a possible explanation/fix?

Thanks

Editted code below:

```
function initialize(){
// Creating a map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.0123601276819, -2.44519164333635),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});


var m = [];

function addMarker(title, lat, lng) {
m = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
map: map,
title: title,  
clickable: true 
});


}



addMarker('Home', 53.0682143712504, -2.52150736731894);
addMarker('Away', 53.0123601276819, -2.44519164333635);



}
```

Comment: This title should be changed because it led me to believe I found the correct question but in the end an unrelated answer. The problem has nothing to do with giving variable names with javascript, it has to do with Google Api not being used properly with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're trying to treat the **object** "m" as if it were an **array**.  Declare it like this:

```
var m = [];
```

and see what happens. There's no "push" function on plain objects, so that line is throwing an exception after your first marker is added.

The Javascript error console, however manifested by the browser you're using, should *always* be open while you're trying out new code.  Well, maybe not *always*, but certainly the minute something weird happens.

*edit* — The call to the `.push()` function in your code is fine; the problem was that you were trying to call it from something that wasn't an array.  All the function does is extend the array with the given element. Javascript arrays are somewhat weird, and the main magic has to do with how the runtime maintains the value of the "length" attribute. You can more directly extend an array like this:

```
arr[arr.length] = newValue;
```

You can also simply use some numeric index computed in some way:

```
arr[pick_a_number()] = newValue;
```

When you do that, the runtime makes sure that the "length" attribute is correctly updated, should the number used as an index be greater than the current value.

Now, back to your updated code. Now it works because you're adding points to the map in succession and not triggering any exceptions. However, by writing:

```
m = google.whatever( ... );
```

you are no longer adding those points to an array - you're *reassigning* the variable "m" to one of the points, over and over again. Change it back to "push" and — if you also change the declaration of "m" as I suggested — it will still work, and you'll get your array populated correctly.

Comment: Thanks !

The premise (as explained by the tut) is that you need to add the markers to an array so you can loop through them and remove them each if you want to.

I have editted my code above. It works perfectly.

Just for my info. Could you perhaps elaborate on what 'push' is, and why can I add a point to my array 'm' by simply writing var m = ''.

In PHP that would REPLACE m..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`m` is scoped to the function it's in so that is not the problem. My guess is that you're getting an error when you call `marker.push(m)`. `marker` is an object and does not have a `push` method. Make it an array (`var marker = []`). Since it is breaking on that line, it never gets to execute the second call to the function. But it has already added the marker on the screen, which is why you see it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable m is in the scope of initialize like the function addMarker.

Each time you set m (which is an array at first) to Marker object, you store a reference to the newly created marker object. That may be the problem as you mentioned.

Instead of setting m to Marker object, use push (a method to add an object to an array) like the following:

```
m.push(new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  map: map,
  title: title,  
  clickable: true 
});).
```